# AJAX call can't find my WebAPI Controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following AJAX call:

```
var params = {
    provider: "facebook"
};

$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/taskpro/api/account/ExternalLogin",
    data: JSON.stringify(params),
    type: "POST",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
})
.done(function (response) {
    alert("Success");
});
```

calling the following WebAPI controller:

```
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public bool ExternalLogin(string provider)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

with the following routemap:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

When I execute this, fiddler is returning:

```
{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 
'http://localhost/taskpro/api/account/ExternalLogin'.","MessageDetail":
"No action was found on the controller 'Account' that matches the request."}
```

I have several other calls being made to this controller that are working just fine.  It's just THIS call that is giving me troubles.

Also, if I remove the parameter in the controller so it's just

```
public bool ExternalLogin()
```

and comment out the data line in the ajax, it works fine.

Any ideas why the routing is not working for this call?

Answer (score 2):

I ran across this article:

http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-post-frombody-parameters-to-web-api/

Basically, WebAPI can't bind to primitive data types like string.  You have to either create a model to bind to, or use the [FromBody] attribute.  I modified my method to this:

```
public bool ExternalLogin([FromBody]string provider)
```

and it's working fine now.

Comment: just fyi..by default `string` data type binds from Uri so in this case Web API was trying to find a value for key called `provider` in the Uri (route data and query string params)...so FromBody decoration is required.

Comment: I had this same problem with missing the FromBody statement, thanks!